# Create a singleton inside a Servlet is unique?

Tags: java, singleton

I have a Java application using the servlet.

I have the necessity to have a singleton populated with different data in relation to the query of the user.

My question is: the singleton is unique for each query?

I mean:

- User1 does a GET (with Alpha param) for instance: `http//www.tango.com/Alpha`. So I create a Singleton with Alpha param;
- User2 does a GET (with Bravo param) for instance: `http//www.tango.com/Bravo`. So I create a Singleton with Bravo param;

These two singleton are different (even on the stack/heap)?

I don't wish to share the information from a query to another query.

Example of Singleton:

```
public class BillPughSingleton {
    private BillPughSingleton() {
        System.out.println("New BillPughSingleton instance returned!");
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
    }

    public static BillPughSingleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And inside of the java program I do this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {        
        [...]
        processRequest(request, response);
        singleton = BillPughSingleton.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Are you really clear on the meaning of the technical term [*singleton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: What if user1 and user2 both use the Alpha param? Do the two requests then share data? How are you creating the "singletons"? What's their lifecycle?

Comment: No, each user uses a different param and the param is given by url (or body of request)

Comment: For singleton I mean: an object that I create one time for each request and populate with the parameters of the request.